# Setting Up JOGL to Eclipse, after that I always got this error

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jogl

**Java OpenGL**
I followed the Video on how to setup the `jogl to Eclipse`. I copied its code and when I compiled, I always got this error.

*

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V    at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1713)
>     at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:77)   at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:201)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:187)    at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2246)   at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:959)  at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:693)   at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:704)   at
>   GL_TestProj.main(GL_TestProj.java:15)

**

and here is the Code i Copied. :

```
import java.awt.Frame;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;

import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;

import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;

import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;

import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;

import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class GL_TestProj implements GLEventListener {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();

        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);

        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(new GL_TestProj());
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        update();
        render(arg0);

    }

    private void render(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GL2 gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex2f(-1, -1);
        gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        gl.glVertex2f(0, 1);
        gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        gl.glVertex2f(1, -1);
        gl.glEnd();
    }

    private void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
            int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and here the youtube Video i Followed . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obdcn01dEz8

Answer (score 0):

Rather use the tutorials of our official wiki, especially this one:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE

As this video hasn't been approved by our community, we cannot ensure that its "advices" are wise. It seems to be very long to explain something very simple.

Don't add jogl-awt.jar into your build path (I wrote it on Youtube in a comment) and it should work. Check that the JARs containing the native libraries are in the same directories than the JARs containing the Java libraries (jogl-all.jar, gluegen-rt.jar).

Edit.: Rather post your question about JOGL on our official forum so that our users can help you too, a very few are on SO.